# Let Them Eat Lists, Eventually (Asynchronous Generic List Consumption with Spring and CompletableFuture)

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, spring

I want to reduce some repeated code in my Java 1.8/Spring Boot application, and to that end I tried to make a reuseable asynchronous utility module. **In essence its an async List.forEach** that takes a List and a consumer for each item of the list. Output is optional.

---

**AsyncUtilImpl**

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Component
public class AsyncUtilImpl implements AsyncUtil {

    private TaskExecutor executor;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor exe){
        this.executor = exe;
    }

    public void configureExecutor(int threadCount){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(threadCount);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(threadCount);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async_thread_");
        executor.initialize();
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public <E> List<Throwable> consumeListAsync(List<E> list, Consumer<E> handler){
        return consumeListAsync(list, handler, this.executor);
    }

    public <E> List<Throwable> consumeListAsync(List<E> list, Consumer<E> consumer, TaskExecutor executor){
        List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            if(executor == null || executor.equals(null)){throw new NullPointerException("Executor null, ensure that your Executor is non-null or else that the local executor is configured");}
            List<CompletableFuture<Void>> asyncTaskList = list
                .stream()
                .map(e -> AsyncCall
                        .accept(consumer, e, executor)
                        .handle((info, error) -> {
                            if(error != null){
                                errors.add(error);
                                return null;
                            }
                            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(info);
                        })
                        .thenCompose(Function.identity())
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());

            CompletableFuture<Void> process =
                CompletableFuture.allOf(asyncTaskList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[asyncTaskList.size()]))
                        .thenRun(() -> asyncTaskList.stream().map(future -> future.join()));

            process.get();

        }catch(Exception e){
            errors.add(e);
        }
        return errors;
    }

    @Async
    private static class AsyncCall{
        public static <E> CompletableFuture<Void> accept(Consumer<E> consumer, E e, Executor executor){
            return CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> consumer.accept(e), executor);
        }
    }

}
```

**An Incomplete explanation of Design/Choices**

Firstly, void returns:
I focused on a void-execution model because of the nature of my app's calls (mostly db CRUD, heavy C and U) These calls have no need of a return type, and this is reflected in my design. **However**, returning data is simple when combined with an Accumulator:

```java
List<SomeType> taskItems = ...
List<SomeOtherType> resultAccumulator = ...
List<Throwable> errors = AsyncUtil.consumeListAsync(
    taskItems,
    (SomeType item)-> resultAccumulator.add(someReturningProcess(item))
);
if(errors.isEmpty()){doSomethingWithResults(resultAccumulator);}
```

Second, errors:
The Async call hides exceptions thrown inside the thread of execution. I .handle these exceptions and create a List of these thread-level exceptions. I return this list of errors, and the user can choose how to respond to these errors. List.isEmpty() indicates completion without errors

---

In the client code, I check for errors like so:

```java
...
List<Throwables> errors = AsyncUtil.consumeListAsync(...);
for(Throwable th : errors){
    if(th instanceof ExecutionException
    || th instanceof InterruptedException){
        throw new RuntimeException(th);
    }else{
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Is this error handling acceptable given the context? Is this good design for a reusable utility? Is it as extensible/configurable as should be expected from a modern utility?**

Any feedback (even feedback that isn't targeting the above questions, and ESPECIALLY feedback as to the format of how I asked this question) is much appreciated